# git equivalent of svn status -u

Tags: git, svn

What's the git equivalent of `svn status -u` or more verbose `svn status --show-updates`. 
The `svn status --show-updates` command shows the updates that the `svn update` command will bring from the server.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question would be better if you stated what the svn command does. This would require only git expertise to answer, and little or none svn knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, I added the necessary explanation.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do it without actually fetching the updates (maybe someone else will). Assuming you are on the default branch "master" and the upstream from which these hypothetical updates will come is the default remote "origin", try....

```
git fetch
git log --name-only ..origin/master
```

Note the double dots .. not a single dot or an elipsis<sup>1</sup>.

This will give you a list of log entries for changes that are only upstream, with the filenames affected, you can alter the parameters to git log to get more or less information.

NB in git "fetching" these updates isn't the same as applying them to your local branch. You no doubt already know how to do that with git pull.

---

<sup>1</sup> As for where do the double dots come from, `name1..name2` indicates a range. If `name1` is omitted, `HEAD` is used in its place. This syntax refers to all commits reachable from `name2` back to, but not including, `HEAD`. [["Git from the bottom up"](http://newartisans.com/2008/04/git-from-the-bottom-up/)]

Comment: +1 Though being relatively new to Git, I had to research a bit to understand why the double dots. After that, I felt myself compelled to extend your answer to help other git newcomers.

Answer (score 31):

Both [Martinho Fernandes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138990/git-equivalent-of-svn-status-u/1139066#1139066) and [tialaramex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138990/git-equivalent-of-svn-status-u/1139046#1139046) answers correctly describe what you need to do.  Let me describe ***why*** it is the way it is.

---

#### Subversion

*Subversion* is **centralized** version control system. It means that it operates in client--server fashion: server stores all the data about version (repository), client has only working directory (files) plus some administrative and helper data. This means that for most commands client has to contact server. This also means that there are many commands asking about state of repository on server, or server configuration, like "`svn status --show-updates`" in question.

*(Sidenote: one helper data that Subversion stores on client are the "pristine" version of files, which means that checking for changes you did doesn't require to connect to server (which is slow)... but it also means that SVN checkout might be larger than Git repository).*

"svn update" (required before commit if repository has any changes in given branch) downloads last version from remote *and* merges (tries to merge) changes you did with changes from remote. IMHO this update-before-commit workflow is not very conductive.

---

#### Git

*Git* is **distributed** version control system. This means that it operates on peer-to-peer fashion: each "client" has all the data about versions (full repository). The central repository is central only because of social convention and not technical limitations. This means that when contacting other remote repository the number of commands "executed remotely" is very small. You can ask for references (heads aka. branches and tags) with "git ls-remote" (and "git update show"), you can pull (get) or push (publish) data with "git fetch" (or "git remote update") / "git push", and if server is configured to allow it you can get snapshot of state of remote repository with "git archive --remote".

So to examine commits which are in remote repository but are not present in your repository you have to download data to your machine. But "git pull" is in fact nothing more than "git fetch" which downloads data and "git merge" which merges it (with a bit of sugar to prepare commit messages and choose which branch to merge). You can then use 'git fetch" (or "git remote update"), examine newly brought commits with "git log" and "gitk" (not being limited to fixed output), and then if everything is all right merge changes with "git merge".

This is not specific to Git, but to all distributed version control systems, although the way SCM presents fetched but unmerged data might differ (Git uses remote-tracking branches in 'remote/<remotename>/*'  namespace, Mercurial from what I understand, uses unnamed heads).

HTH

Comment: Your answer is essentially a rationalisation of why `svn status -u` requires *two* git commands, which can actually be various different commands (`get remote update`, `git fetch`, etc). However, the basis of your rationalisation is incorrect. You say "each 'client' has all the data about versions (full repository). The central repository is central only because of social convention and not technical limitations". This is not true in real-life scenarios, where local repos are generally out of date compared to the central company/whatever repo.

Comment: @EML Your comment is incorrect. 1) You said this answer is a rationalization with a negative tone, which is nonsense. That comment was pointless, inflammatory, and misguided. 2) The basis of this answer is correct and accurate. The whole point of `git fetch` is to do the opposite of what you're attempting to describe as a shortcoming of git, so you are entirely wrong unfortunately. If you expect to see updates without updating anything, you are using the tool wrong. `git fetch` does download the entire repository history as explained in the answer.

Answer (score 13):

If you fetch:

```
git fetch <remote>
```

instead of pulling:

```
git pull <remote>
```

from the remote, you can then inspect what changed with `git log`. To apply the changes:

```
git merge <remote>/<remote-branch>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `git ls-remote` to list the SHA of references in a remote repository; so, you can see if there are any changes by comparing the output of:

```
$ git show-ref origin/master     # <-- Where this repo thinks "origin/master" is
5bad423ae8d9055d989a66598d3c4473dbe97f8f refs/remotes/origin/master
$ git ls-remote origin master    # <-- Where "origin" thinks "master" is
060bbe2125ec5e236a6c6eaed2e715b0328a9106    refs/heads/master
```

If they differ, then there are changes to fetch:

```
$ git remote update
Fetching origin
...
From github.com:xxxx/yyyy
5bad423..060bbe2  master     -> origin/master
```

Answer (score 3):

For me, just to display files that will changed, it's :

```
git fetch (1)
git diff --name-only ..origin/master (2)
```

1. Fetches changes in the Git "database" (the .git directory only) and do not alter files.
2. Shows names of files that will changed after a merge

To updates files (not only Git "database") do a git merge

Answer (score 2):

Gits gives us more tools to check an "update". First you have to "download" the up-to-date state of the repository:

```
git fetch
```

Now you can get the list of the changed files:

```
git log --name-status ..origin/master
```

Additionaly, you can see the full list of changes with diff:

```
git diff ..origin/master
```

Meaning of the starting letters are: Added (A), Copied (C), Deleted (D), Modified (M), Renamed (R), changed (T), are Unmerged (U), are Unknown (X), or have had their pairing Broken (B)

Answer (score 2):

`git fetch && git log --name-status ..origin/master` does indeed show the logs that would be merged.  However, it also pulls the changes.  It's not technically possible to do the same exact thing as `svn status -u`, but `git fetch` is so fast that usually it shouldn't matter

If you absolutely need the log before fetching, the only way would be to connect (SSH or equivalent) into the remote and issue `git log` there.