# Download a prior git commit from repository

Tags: git

Im simply trying to download a prior commit because a gem corrupted my local files. I've tried the suggestions outlined in the answer below but get the following error after cloning the repository and checkingout into the commit: 'You are not currently on a branch, so I cant use any branch..merge' in your configuration file.'

[How do I download a specific git commit from a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697707/how-do-i-download-a-specific-git-commit-from-a-repository)

Comment: Want to understand what you mean by 'download' a certain commit (lets say commit ABC) - do you have a repository where you want to wipe out your local changes (if any) and point your local branch to ABC?  Or are you planning on cloning, changing your local copy to ABC, taking some file, and deleting the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt realize that I could manually download a particular commit by clicking the download as zip button once inside the commit code section. I incorrectly assumed that this button only allowed one to download the most recent commit.