# Clone only a specific commit using git

Tags: git

I have to build a patched kernel based on the 4.1.2 mainline kernel. I know that I need the commit `$commit_num`. Unfortunately, my network connection is slow, so downloading the whole repo with history would take ages.

Is it possible to download only this one commit? I don't have the repo cloned.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pull a specific commit from a remote Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872486/pull-a-specific-commit-from-a-remote-git-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3761854/1475346), the only thing you can try is

`git archive -o kernel.tar --remote=git://${YOUR_GIT_REPO_URL} ${YOUR_GIT_HASH}`

Answer (score 0):

If the host allows it, you can use `git archive` to get a zipped up tree of files:

```
git archive --format=zip --remote=git://git.foo.com/project.git <commit-or-tag>
```