# Have anyone use gollum-site to generete markdown wikis and host it on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, github, wiki, gollum-wiki

Hi i have tried using [gollum-site gem](https://github.com/dreverri/gollum-site), but it seems to only generate the site on localhost:8000 by default. How can i get the markdown wiki hosted on heroku. Anyone tried doing it before ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploy Gollum wiki to Heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047999/deploy-gollum-wiki-to-heroku)

Comment: Not a duplicate, this question is about gollum-site, and not about gollum alone.

Answer (score 0):

There was [a thread on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047999/deploy-gollum-wiki-to-heroku) a while ago. It looks like it isn't possible because of Heroku's readonly filesystem and the fact that you don't have access to git.

> So, the solution will be to clone the repo to temporary path, work there and push changes to the remote repo. There is a much overhead: you need to clone repo every time a user browse a wiki page. *— Vanuan*

Comment: Because this question isn't about gollum, but gollum-site. It should be possible with the right configuration. gollum-site will generate static html pages that are served, so not need to access the filesystem in the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

There is [GitHub repository: heroku-buildpack-gollum-site](https://github.com/philippbosch/heroku-buildpack-gollum-site) that seem to do just what you want. It uses a modified version
of [heroku-buildpack-php](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php) to install an Apache pack to heroku.

The answers targeted to Gollum are not appropriate, as here any server can serve the static generated site. No need to host Gollum (or Gollum-site) itself.

*The question is old now, but some people can still need the answer!*