# Fetch changesets from a remote Git repository

Tags: git, logging

I'd like to fetch changesets (to display them somewhere) from a git repository w/o cloning it on my local machine, just like svn does (svn log http://...). Is it something you can do using git? I've looked into the git log documentation but I couldn't find what I needed.

Thanks!

Comment: See also [Browse and display files in a git repo without cloning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178389/browse-and-display-files-in-a-git-repo-without-cloning)

Answer (score 3):

No, Git does not deal in changesets, you have to clone the repository before you can use it. The project in question might have a web interface for the repository which might allow you to create a diff between two arbitrary versions.

Answer (score 3):

You can work with remote repositories without cloning the whole repository, yes. However you are limited in what you do:

To inspect a repository for available branches:

```
git ls-remote git://url/to/repository.git
```

To fetch a single branch:

```
git fetch git://url/to/repository.git branch
```

This will fetch the branch as `FETCH_HEAD` you then need to checkout that branch, and can save it to a local branch (otherwise you don't have any direct reference to its head):

```
git checkout FETCH_HEAD
git checkout -b my-external-branch
```

If you plan to work with an external repository more often, it makes sense to add it as a remote (even if you don't plan to fetch everything):

```
git remote add ext-repository git://url/to/repository.git
```

Then you can either fetch the whole repository:

```
git fetch ext-repository
```

or again just single branches:

```
git fetch ext-repository branch
```

Comment: Well, it does fetch the changesets, and afterwards he can display it :P

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't fetch changesets, I finally went with cloning the whole repository.

Answer (score -1):

What about

```
git log --name-status
```

looks more or less like svn log ...or

```
git log -5 --name-status
```