# How to get the latest commit hash on remote using gitpython?

Tags: python-3.x, git, gitpython

Is there a way that I can get the most recent commit on a remote repository using gitpython?
I do not want to perform operations like a pull or merge on my local branch. I also do not want to depend on the master branch on my local to get this information. All I have is a valid repo out there, and I am using `repo.remotes.origin.url` to get the information.

With just the repo URL, can I get the most recent commit on that repository?

Comment: How about `fetch`, would that be okay?

Comment: @matt well, yeah that could work. I am wondering if I can somehow achieve this without having to deal with github token

Comment: @Shrav did my response below answer your question, or do you want to keep digging? I know it's not ideal, but such is life.

Comment: @DV82XL Thank you! It did answer my question. However, my use case is a little different as I have to do this on Buildkite without having to mount the ssh creds. I ended up creating a new plugin that sets up the repo before doing the git operations inside a docker container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using gitpython, you can't do this without a local clone. Git is a distributed system, so it's designed for users to operate on their local repos. These answer gives some decent explanations and alternatives:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28524371/5752730
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19391097/5752730
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16579859/5752730

#### Using gitpython - requires local repo

You can do a shallow clone (for speed), get latest commit SHA using `git rev-parse` or `git ls-remote`, then delete the local repo.

```py
import git
from pathlib import Path

repo_url = 'https://github.com/path/to/your/repo.git'
local_repo_dir = Path('/path/to/your/repo')

# delete the repo if it exists, perform shallow clone, get SHA, delete repo
local_repo_dir.unlink(missing_ok=True)
repo = git.Repo.clone_from(repo_url, local_repo_dir, depth=1)
sha = repo.rev_parse('origin/master')
local_repo_dir.unlink()
print(sha)
```

#### Using python subprocess - does not require local repo

This simpler solution uses `git ls-remote`, which does not require a local clone. The following uses `subprocess` to get the SHA-1 of the given branch from the remote repo without a local clone. Note that the SHA needs to be extracted from the output response by splitting at the first tab.

```py
import subprocess
import re

repo_url = 'https://github.com/path/to/your/repo.git'
process = subprocess.Popen(["git", "ls-remote", repo_url], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
sha = re.split(r'\t+', stdout.decode('ascii'))[0]
print(sha)
```

Comment: `git ls-remote` doesn't require a local clone, you can give it a remote URL as an argument. I don't think `gitpython` can deal with it though.

Comment: That's right. `git ls-remote` would have to be called using a subprocess call.

Answer (score 4):

You *can* do it with `gitpython` without creating a local repository first:

```py
remote_heads = git.cmd.Git().ls_remote(repo_url, heads=True)
```

Comment: Although this is not documented, it works.