# Can we get list of commits from a remote Git server instead of local repository

Tags: git, tfs, tfs-sdk

I am using Git for source code version control in TFS 2013.

I need to programmatically connect to the Git master repository on TFS server using TFS API or others to list all the commits instead of listing from a cloned local repository.

Is there anyone able to enlighten on this?
Thanks very much.

Comment: Do you really need *all* the commits, or would you be happy with just the references (branches and tags) and their associated commit IDs?

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178389/browse-and-display-files-in-a-git-repo-without-cloning

Comment: Thanks @Jubobs! I need the commits instead of just the references from the remote repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git is a distributed system.  The only thing that makes a particular repo the "master" is that you and the others accessing it regard it as such.  So the way to ask about remote changes is to retrieve a copy of them locally.  So figure out what remote corresponds to the server in question: it might be "origin" or "tfs" or whatever.

```
git fetch [REMOTE_NAME]
### or just
git fetch --all
### then
git log --pretty=oneline [REMOTE_NAME]/[BRANCH_NAME]
```

For every locally tracked branch the corresponding remote branch state is maintained under the remote/branch namespace.