# How do i get commit logs of a remote located branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote, git-log

Without cloning the repository, Is it possible to get the following from command-line/git bash,

1. List of branches in the repository
2. git logs of specific branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i am aware the only way to do is to connect to server using ssh and running the git log on the server

```
ssh remote@host "cd repo && git log"
```

Fo windows u can use [Putty](http://www.putty.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if its possible to get logs without cloning, but once you've cloned its as easy as something like `git log origin/dev` where `origin` is the remote repo and `dev` is the branch in question to get logs without checking out the branch.

There is another similar question that relies on running ssh commands remotely on the repo's server. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1178586/563381