# git: Interrogate "remote" repository

Tags: git

Let's say I have a public repo on Github or some private server. 
If I had a clone of it to my machine, I could have ran commands like:

```
git branch
```

or

```
git-show
```

etc. in order to know more about a repository. 
Obviously something like github has a GUI which you can use to get these information. I was wondering however if there is a way of getting these information from the command line without `clone`ing it or `ssh`ing to the remote machine and `cd`ing to the directory hosting the repository.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178389/browse-and-display-files-in-a-git-repo-without-cloning (IMO). Please look there for `git-ls-remote` hint ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short answer is 'no' - there isn't a lot of interrogation you can do remotely unless, like Github, that repo also has a front-end UI that's accessible remotely.

@Dilettant is right - you might find something you want in `git help ls-remote`

If you did want a lighter-weight clone of the repo, the `--bare` or `--mirror` options copy only the git database (meaning you have no working directory). The latter is designed to be used with `git remote update` to provide a more-or-less exact copy of the remote repo.

I don't know what it is you're looking to achieve, but remember that there's no reason you can't have multiple local clones of the same repo, and that you can fetch from one (including local clones) and push to another.