# How to get the list of files from particular repo in github using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, github

Something similar to this - [How to get list of files from a specific GitHub repo(Link) in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46302570/how-to-get-list-of-files-from-a-specific-github-repolink-in-c-sharp) , but using PowerShell.

Comment: SO has rules, we are to follow: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). PowerShell is .Net based, and all of .Net is avaialbe to you. You can use C# in PS scripts. Just search for examples regarding that use case.

Comment: There are many Q&A's on SO regarding PowerShell and GitHub. Just use the serach box above: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=powershell+github or the web in general.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft already provides cmdlets for github use cases.

> PowerShellForGitHub
>
> https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerShellForGitHub

Even the link you post gave you an answer:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/crs2007/ActiveReport/contents/ActiveReport
```

curl is an alias in PowerShell

```
Get-Alias -Name curl
# Results
<#
 Get-Alias -Name curl

CommandType     Name                       Version    Source                                                                                              
-----------     ----                       -------    ------                                                                                              
Alias           curl -> Invoke-WebRequest 
#>

# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Invoke-WebRequest ).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Invoke-WebRequest ).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Invoke-WebRequest  -Examples
Get-help -Name Invoke-WebRequest  -Full
Get-help -Name Invoke-WebRequest  -Online
```