# Fetch references from remote git repo

Tags: git

I want to get the refs for a remote git repo (I am not interested in the code).

I am connecting over ssh. What commands would I need to execute to just download the refs information?

Comment: `refs` [means branches and tags](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch), which means commits, which means code. Please clarify what, exactly, you want to fetch.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the [`--depth=` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#git-fetch---depthltdepthgt), so that you don't have to download a lot of commits?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to run some version of [ls-remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote)

By default it only shows you the branches:

`git ls-remote ssh://user@server/path/to/repo.git`

use `-t` to show the tags:

`git ls-remote -t ssh://user@server/path/to/repo.git`

add `-h` to show the branches also:

`git ls-remote -t -h ssh://user@server/path/to/repo.git`

Comment: yeah this is the kind of thing I am looking for - I also want to see which commits make up the branch - is that possible?

Comment: There is no `remote log` command that I am aware of, nor do any turn up in my google searches. Closest thing I know of to do what you want is to to something like: `ssh user@server "cd path/to/repo.gt && git log"`

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178389/browse-and-display-files-in-a-git-repo-without-cloning

Answer (score 0):

I guess [`git ls-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote) is the Git command you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
git fetch origin branch
```

fetches updates from origin for a single  branch.

```
git remote update origin
```

fetches updates from origin for all branches.