# How can I get a list of the files in a directory in a remote repository?

Tags: git

I want to get a list of file names in a directory on my master branch without cloning the repository.

I've looked at ls-file and ls-tree but they only seem to work locally. My current solution is to use `git-archive` and split the content using pattern matching.

My current regex for a file path is `^\/?([A-z0-9-_+]+\/)*([A-z0-9-_+]+(\.[A-z0-9]+)?)$`

"over the wire" I want to receive something like

```
file_1.file
file_2.file
...
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178389/browse-and-display-files-in-a-git-repo-without-cloning

Comment: @rprakash From that answer "... but you **cant** show history or list directories or anything of that level ..."

\n
If you can demonstrate that it **is** possible could you please provide an example to get the files in `/dir/path`

Comment: you can not do it directly. if you can ssh to the remote site, do it as in the answer above. Otherwise to fetch first and check its contents with ls-tree.

Comment: @NolanDougherty Sometimes "you cannot" is the answer and you have to accept that. `git` cannot list files in the remote. So you have to get the files locally either with `clone` or `archive`. If you have access to the remote repo outside of `git` (ssh or http(s)) you can try list files with that access. For example, Github and Gitlab provide API-over-HTTP. But that's not `git`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. I'll have to work around this I guess.