# git fetch vs pull (need full merge syntax)

Tags: git

So I've read plenty of answers on this already, saying that pull = fetch + merge. But I'm not totally convinced. This morning instead of doing a "git pull" to update my code with everyone's changes, I did "git fetch," and then ran "git merge" which resulted in a bunch of errors. Actually, "git merge" didn't work on its own. I'm on the origin/develop branch, so I did "git merge origin develop" and it gave me several errors (which I didn't save, unfortunately).

So, what is the EXACT syntax I should've used?

Comment: You may have run into a merge conflict. Hard to tell if you don't have the messages. See here that git merge does indeed use the default upstream if no commit argument is given: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html

Comment: Hmm, maybe you don't have the config var set that enables upstream as default--I don't know what happens when it isn't. Here's another answer that might clarify though: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3427698/382780

Comment: "I'm on the origin/develop branch"? If you want to merge with the remote branch, say `origin/develop`, you should stay at the local branch, say `develop`, and then run `git merge origin/develop`.

Comment: Sorry, edited my Q.. I had actually typed "git merge origin develop." Argh. If there's ONE thing I hate about git, it's the syntax inconsistency ("git merge origin/develop" vs "git push origin develop"). I feel like they should've stuck with the slash syntax across the board. So this is probably why I encountered an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should've used `git merge @{u}`.  `@{u}` is shorthand for the remote tracking branch (e.g., `origin/master`).  It looks like you might be working with a branch called `develop`, so this would be the equivalent: `git merge origin/develop`.

I can't remember if `pull` will now ask you to provide a message for an actual merge--in the case that it cannot just fast-forward.  So, the full command might be more akin to `git merge --no-edit @{u}`.

Comment: Whoa. Where can I get a full list of those shortcuts?

Comment: Look in the "Specifying Revisions" section of [`git rev-parse` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) (you can get to it via `git help rev-parse` too).

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack I would like to point out that if you're using Git bash tab-completion, simply typing `git merge or` then hitting tab should autocomplete to `git merge origin/`, then typing `de` and hitting tab again should autocomplete the whole thing to `git merge origin/develop`. **Problem solved**!