# how to find status of my code with regard to my app's git repo on heroku

Tags: git, heroku, status

I have created an app on heroku and pushed my code (after creating git repo by `git init`).
My `app` folder contains a `requirements.txt` in which I wrongfully put `matplotlib` before `numpy`. (Actually `numpy` is needed to install `matpplotlib` and so should come before it).

When I  pushed to `heroku master,`the compilation failed with an error message 'numpy is needed to install matplotlib'.
So I corrected the order of items in `requirements.txt` and using `git add`, `git commit` etc committed it.
Then I tried to push the code again using `git push heroku master`.
But it failed with the same error message

here is the `requirements.txt`

```
Django==1.4.3
South==0.7.6
distribute==0.6.28
dj-database-url==0.2.1
django-registration==0.8
numpy==1.6.2
matplotlib==1.2.0
psycopg2==2.4.6
python-memcached==1.48
wsgiref==0.1.2
simplejson==3.0.7
```

Then I tried to find the status using

`git status` and it produced

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
# nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

I used to add my code to Github.
I think the `origin/master` relates to that. Am I wrong?

How do I find the status of my commit on heroku?
My app has a name say `git@heroku.com:myapp.git`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the status, you have several options:

- "[git: check if pull needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258243/git-check-if-pull-needed)":

```
git remote -v update
git status -uno
```

- "[git equivalent of `svn status -u`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138990/git-equivalent-of-svn-status-u)":

```
git fetch heroku
git log --name-only ..heroku/master
```

---

Check if `origin` does point to `heroku` or not:

```
git remote -v
```

In that case, a simple `git push` isn't enough

Depending on your default push policy, you might want to make sure your branch has `heroku/master` as upstream branch:

```
git push -u heroku master
```

Comment: I was doing `git push heroku master`

Comment: @damon then I would try to simplify and push a requirements.txt without `numpy` is needed to install `matpplotlib`, then one with just `numpy`, then one with both. If the very first push fails, then it is another issue entirely.

Comment: @damon I have edited the answer to address the status point of your question.

Comment: thanks for the input regarding status.. as you advised,I pushed a req file with only numpy and it compiled..then I pushed the req file without numpy, but adding matplotlib,and everything installed properly..It gives an error when numpy and matplotlib are both in the req file..

Comment: @damon strange, that seems to be an heroku oddity, then.