# How to access a GIT server log without a local archive

Tags: git

I have a client with a private GIT server and a number of local GIT installs with clones of the archive. They want to log all commits into a database. I know I can do this with a local GIT Clone, but for privacy reasons don't want a clone on the server just for the database operations. ls-remote won't work as they won't give me access to any of the system with clones, I only have access to the server system.

Is there a way to access a GIT Server without a local repository? All my searches got muddles by the number of api's in GITHUB.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178389/browse-and-display-files-in-a-git-repo-without-cloning does this help?

Comment: That is the ls-remote I mentioned. I would have to still access a cloned archive rather than the server itself.

Comment: Not related to your question, but git is not an acronym. Don't capitalise it as if it were. (The same goes for GitHub.)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can't. Git being distributed, no operation happen on the server other than fetch and push (*that's really basic explanation*). Checkout this answer for more: [git equivalent of svn status -u](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138990/git-equivalent-of-svn-status-u/1140711#1140711)

So, you can use a web interface like Github or Bitbucket - but I guess you're self host, so there's well known Git-Web and some other open source visualisation tool (Gitlab and some other). - You could also `ssh` onto your repository machine and do git commands over there.

Or simply, you clone the repo on your machine and check it out there.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Even git -fetch does not work for me as the repro is shallow. I am going to have to look at passive encryption.